# How to add ID of one mongoose collection to an array in another collection?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm trying to add the ID of my category documents to my budget documents. Below is the Schema for my budgets.

```js
var {mongoose} = require('../db/mongoose'); 


var budgetsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        year: Number,
        categoryIDs: [{type:mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: 'categories'}]
}); 

var Budgets = mongoose.model('Budgets', budgetsSchema);

module.exports = {
    Budgets
};
```

And here is the Schema for my categories collection.

```js
var {mongoose} = require('../db/mongoose'); 

var categorySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    amount: Number, 
    sub_categories: [{
        name: String,
        amount: Number
    }]
})

var categories = mongoose.model('categories', categorySchema); 

module.exports = {
    categories 
};
```

To post categories, I use this express post request to add the categories to the category collection and its ID to the Budget collection.

```js
//The ID is the Budget ID
app.post('/categories/:id', (req, res) => {
            var id = req.params.id;
            var sub_categories = req.body.sub_categories; 
            var category = new categories({
                name: req.body.name, 
                amount: req.body.amount, 
                sub_categories 
            })

            category.save().then((docs) => {
                res.send(docs);
                console.log(docs)
            }).catch((e) => res.status(404).send(e)); 

            Budgets.findById(id).then((docs) => {
                if(!docs) {
                    res.status(404).send();
                }
                docs.categoryIDs.push(category._id);
            }).catch((e) => {
                res.send(e).status(404);
            })
        })
```

When I run this, it does add the category to the collection, but it does not add the ID to the categoryIDs array in the Budget document. Please help

Answer (score 1):

First, change the model name from `Plural` to `Singular` as mentioned in the [mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html#compiling) to avoid confusion:

> The first argument is the singular name of the collection your model
>   is for. Mongoose automatically looks for the plural version of your
>   model name. Thus, for the example above, the model Tank is for the
>   tanks collection in the database. The .model() function makes a copy
>   of schema. Make sure that you've added everything you want to schema
>   before calling .model()!

So `categories` to `Category` and `Budgets` to `Budget`. Please verify the `new` before `mongoose.model` here, [Mongoose docs ref](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#definition).

```
var categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    amount: Number, 
    sub_categories: [{
        name: String,
        amount: Number
    }]
})
```